# Efficient fuzzy string comparison over thousands of text files

Tags: python, nlp, fuzzy-search

I need to search several thousand plaintext files for a set of names.  I'm generating trigrams to retain context.  I need to account for minor misspellings, so I'm using a Levenshtein distance calculation, function lev().  I need the final result to return the name with a hit, the filename the hit was in, and the trigram that was marked a hit.  My python program works as expected, but very slowly.  I'm searching for a faster way to do this search, preferably in python, but my Googlefu has failed me.  A generic-ified version of the program is below:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import os

textfiles = []
newgrams = set()
ngrams = []
hitlist = []
path = 'path of folder of textfiles'
names = ['john james doe', 'jane jill doe']

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(input = 'filename', ngram_range = (3,3), 
                         strip_accents='unicode', stop_words='english', 
                         token_pattern='[a-zA-Z\-]\\w*', 
                         encoding='utf-8', decode_error = 'replace', lowercase = True)
ngramer = vectorizer.build_analyzer()

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for files in filenames:
        if files.endswith('.txt'):
            textfiles.append(files)

ctFiles = len(textfiles)
ctNames = len(names)

for i in range(ctFiles):
    newgrams = set(ngramer(path+'/'+textfiles[i]))
    ngrams.append(newgrams)

for i in range(ctNames):
    splitname = names[i].split()
    for j in range(ctFiles):
        tempset = set()
        for k in range(len(splitname)):
            if k == 0:
            ## subset only the trigrams that "match" first name
            for trigram in ngrams[j]:
                    for word in trigram.split():
                        if lev(splitname[k], word) < 2:
                            tempset.add(trigram)
            else:
            ## search that subset for middle/last name
            if len(tempset) > 0:
                    for trigram in tempset:
                        for word in trigram.split():
                            if lev(splitname[k], word) < 2:
                                hitlist.append([names[i], textfiles[j], trigram])
print(hitlist) ## eventually save to CSV
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using fuzzywuzzy, it's pretty fast on my dataset (100K sentences) https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy

Answer (score 0):

Levenshtein is very expensive, and I wouldn't recommend using it in fuzzy matching on this many documents (unless you want to build a levenshtein automata to generate an index of tokens n steps away from every word in your files).

Trigram indexing should be fast and accurate on its own for words of a certain length, although you mention names and if that means multiple words, chunks need to be indexed as well then that needs to be implemented.

If you try trigram indexing on its own, and aren't satisfied with the accuracy, you can try adding a trigram chunk index aka (Ban, ana, nan) as a tuple in addition to Ban, nan, and ana as individual trigrams, but in a separate index. This will have an even larger decrease in accuracy as character length decreases, and so that should be accounted for.

Key here is that levenshtein executes at O(length of query^length of word in file*number of words in files) while token/trigram/chunk indexing executes at O(log(number of words in files)*number of tokens/chunks/trigrams in query).